# Is there a way to modify C# code with C#?

Tags: c#, class

How can I add a statement `public int ID { get; set; }` to the class below programmatically?

```
public class DgItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it's totally possible. read file, regex replace, write file. better with some syntax checking/formatting libraries.

Comment: Not sure what actual problem you are trying to solve, but maybe partial classes would help?

Comment: I removed the "wpf" tag from your question as it is not related to WPF technology

Comment: Thanks! Your reminding is greatly appreciated. @Jeremy Lakeman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use T4 Templates!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
public class DgItem
{
<# for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
#>
    public string Name<#= i #> { get; set; }
<# }
#>
}
```

output:

```
public class DgItem
{
    public string Name0 { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
    public string Name4 { get; set; }
    public string Name5 { get; set; }
    public string Name6 { get; set; }
    public string Name7 { get; set; }
    public string Name8 { get; set; }
    public string Name9 { get; set; }
}
```